# How can I get posts by year/month with nextjs and contentful?

Tags: javascript, next.js, contentful

I'm creating a blog with Next.js using Contentful CMS.

My folder structure looks like this right now **pages/blog/[year]/[month]/[slug].js**

*The year and month folder each has its own index.js*

Right now I'm working on the year part it, this is how I generated the paths for all years which contains any blog post.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  let data = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blog_post',
    select: 'sys.id,fields.publishDate',
    limit: 1000,
  })

  const allYears = data.items
    .map((item) => moment(item.fields.publishDate).format('YYYY'))
    .sort()

  // Get unique values.
  const years = [...new Set(allYears)]

  // Create paths.
  const paths = years.map((year) => {
    return {
      params: { year },
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

So far so good, but I have no idea how to query my contentful posts in getStaticProps? Maybe contentful doesn't support it? The only other way I would be able to do it is to filter all posts manually, but that doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { year } }) {
  let data = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blog_post',
    // I assume I somehow have to pass my year in the query
  })

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  }
}
```

Contentful returns date strings like this: 2021-03-03T00:00+01:00

So my question is, how could I best solve this? Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: What do you want to get from Contentful in that `getStaticProps`? All blog posts for a given year?

Comment: Yes exactly, and then the same procedure for [month].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [range operators](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/ranges) on the `pusblishDate` field to filter the results down to the given year.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { year } }) {
    const nextYear = parseInt(year, 10) + 1 // May need to parse if `year` is a string
    let data = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'blog_post',
        'fields.publishDate[gte]': `${year}-01-01T00:00:00Z`,
        'fields.publishDate[lt]': `${nextYear}-01-01T00:00:00Z`
    })

    return {
        props: { data }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks, this is it! I'm sure i'll figure out the month part =).